# C++ String matching and replacing using look up file

Tags: c++, string, replace

I am new in C++.C++ function will work like below. 
**Look up file :**

```
POST OFFICE,PO
SUITE ACCESS ROOM, SAR
SUITE,STE
STREET,ST
NEW YORK,NY
POST,PST
LONG LINE STREET,LLS
```

There will be one c++ function which should have one parameter like "`ARIJIT, 192 POST OFFICE, SUITE`" and it will give output like "`ARIJIT, 192 PO, STE`". it will use one static look up file like upper content.

I did below code structure but not finding in which direction to go..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    char * processAddress (char *input );
    char *input = "ARIJIT, 192 POST OFFICE, SUITE";
    char *output = processAddress(input);
    std::cout << output;
    return 0;
}

char * processAddress (char *input ) {
    char *output = input;

    std::ifstream file("LookUp.csv");
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        std:: cout << str << '\n';
    }
    return output;
}
```

Problem I am facing

```
1. How to map look up file

2. Find and Replace
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to read the file and create a data structure (map) from it. Then you'll have to try to locate all the key strings ("POST OFFICE") in that parameter, and *then* you'll be able to use replace. But be aware of the possibility of one key string being a substring of another one, as in "STREET" and "LONG LINE STREET". Ordering key strings by descending length might help.

Comment: Your first line shows nothing about your personal efforts to solve this problem. You need to give us an example. What is your input, what is your expected and actual output? How did you read the file and store it's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys

I solved it below is the code .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
int main()
{
    std::string processAddress (std:: string input);
    std::string input = "ARIJIT, 192 POST OFFICE, SUITE";
    std::string output = processAddress(input);
    std::cout << output << "\n";
    return 0;
}

std::string processAddress (std:: string input) {
    void replaceAll(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to);
    std::ifstream file("LookUp.csv");
    std::string str;
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MyMap;
    MyMap my_map;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        std::string delimiter = ",";
        std::string token1 = str.substr(0, str.find(delimiter));
        std::string token2 = str.substr(token1.length()+1, str.find(delimiter));
        my_map[token1] = token2;
    }
    // Map Enumeration
    for( MyMap::const_iterator it = my_map.end(); it != my_map.begin(); --it )
    {
        std::string key = it->first;
        std::string value = it->second;
        // find and replace
        replaceAll(input, key, value);
    }

    std::string output = input ;
    return output;
}
bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}
void replaceAll(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    if(from.empty())
        return;
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length(); // In case 'to' contains 'from', like replacing 'x' with 'yx'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've loaded the strings from the file, split on the comma, and stored them in an accessible manner, the replace call you're looking for should be something like this:

```
size_t pos = input.find(toReplace); // toReplace = "text to replace"
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    input.replace(pos, toReplace.length(), shorterString); // shorterString = "new text"
} else {
    // Your "text to replace" doesn't exist in input
}
```